# Создание службы на андроид

Tags: java, android

есть потребность создание службы на телефон, выполнять будет функцию оповещения с веб сервера, но дело в том что само приложение не нужно, не нужно что бы оно висело в меню приложений, просто служба в фоне и все. это возможно реализовать?

Comment: Да, это возможно реализовать.

Comment: Отлично, тогда нужно погуглить получше, спасибо)

Comment: Можно начать отсюда: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-workmanager-2083bcfc4712

Comment: А ни у кого нет примера? я понимаю что я должен отключить UI но пока что не понимаю как... та и установка как будет проходить? т.е. приложение все равно будет... не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если добавить следующий код в `OnCreate()` в `MainActivity`, то приложение будет скрыто (его всё равно можно будет найти через настройки):

```
String pgkname = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        ComponentName componentToDisable = new ComponentName(pgkname, pgkname+".MainActivity");
        getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(componentToDisable, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

//Выполняем какие-либо действия

finish();
```